# How can I work with arrays fetched thru AJAX once?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I'm making a site where the user can move some sliders to have different results dynamically. Right now, while developing locally, I'm monitoring the "update" status from each slider and fetch the data from the DB using AJAX. I'm 100% sure it will not be ideal when the site is live so, I was wondering how to improve it hence my question: Can I make one single AJAX call on page load to fetch several arrays of data and then map the resulting arrays as javascript variables somehow? Even if it's not asyncronusly as it will only do it once.

Right now, while testing, I get the following from AJAX:
[image: Console output of successfully fetched data]

And the data produced by PHP is like the following:

```
Array
(
    [lamps] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [lamp_id] => 1
                    [wattage] => 50
                    [lumens] => 6750
                    [price] => 1132.00
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [lamp_id] => 2
                    [wattage] => 100
                    [lumens] => 13500
                    [price] => 2905.00
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [lamp_id] => 3
                    [wattage] => 150
                    [lumens] => 13575
                    [price] => 4608.00
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [lamp_id] => 4
                    [wattage] => 200
                    [lumens] => 18100
                    [price] => 5360.00
                )

        )

    [panels] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [panel_id] => 1
                    [watts] => 260
                    [voltage] => 31.35
                    [price] => 4653.00
                )

        )

)
```

I know how to handle a single return from AJAX but really don't have a clue on how to handle an array, let alone two of them... but I'm guessing that I could map them somehow so I can call the vars by each [arrayname][arraykey]?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `json_encode($theWholePHPDataStructure)` creates a JSON String. Echo that to the AJAX call and it will automagically become a javascript object

Comment: You called `console.log(x)` to produce that output. Which means `x` already is a JS object. The lamps array is `x.lamps`, and the panel array is `x.panel`. That's all there is to it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder _but I'm guessing that I could map them somehow so I can call the vars by each [arrayname][arraykey]?_

Comment: I am sure it is relevant. I will reopen because you are complaining, but I am still sure it is a matter of parsing JSON

Comment: When I say parse, I mean parse and iterate - parsing without iterating - examples which are in the dupe I posted is not interesting

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, Objects `{}` can be accessed like this: `object.property` or `object[property]` and Arrays `[]` are accessed like this: `array[index]`.

From your example, to access the first lamp, you would use: `Object.lamps[0].lamp_id`